# Where to start when trying to retrieve data with requests and responses coded in XML and HTTP is the protocol

Tags: java, xml, sockets

To start, I am a newbie programmer and have taken on a summer job after finishing first year in college this year.  I have been asked to write code to program requests and responses coded in XML.  I have been told that requests are made via the POST command and both request parameters and the responses are carried out in the body of the HTTP which are sent and received from a specific URL.  I have been given the command format for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <cmd action="read_val" user="username" password="*****">
     <val cid="0" node="1" vid="100" set="5" nodetype="16"/>
   </cmd>
```

I have searched high and low and have found loads of different information on the topic but there are all too technical for me at the moment.  I need 'baby steps' help.  This is a small company and there are no other programmers to ask questions and advice.

I am learning Java in college and have used this site many times and have found it very useful.  I can open sockets, bind sockets etc in java and read back in data input on forms but where would I use the above code.  How do I connect together the java I know with the XML above.  I know I am in over my head but I have been trying to figure this out for the last 3-4 weeks with no joy and my head is about to burst.

At the other end of the URL is a monitor capturing ongoing data such as pressure and temperature.  The connection made is being used to read in the data at a set interval and stored in a database.  If I could get the data going to a System.out.println I could manage the rest!!

I have looked at so many examples and read so much information that I don't know where to begin - do I use netbeans and java or is it something different that I need to know.

Sorry about this and thanks in advance!

Comment: if your are developing a server application using XML as input/output, you may have a look at SOAP and JAX-WS. There are various tutorials on the web which explain how to create a WSDL (a web-service definition) and generate all the java class from it. The JAX-WS framework "encapsulate" all the socket communication and XML from/to conversions mechanisms (done by JAXB).

Comment: Thank you for replying Francois, I will begin looking into this now.  I obviously wasn't looking at the right information before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you are trying to do is "**Consuming an XML REST Service**" (this is what you might want to google).

There are several ways to do it, and it really depends on what libraries you want to use.

A good start would be splitting the problem into several parts.

- **Creating a class that contains all the information you need to send.** (So it can be easily manipulated in Java)
- **Mapping the class to the XML.** (So you can transform the Java Objects to XML and vice-versa)
- **Consuming the Service.** (this would be sending the POST request to the server with the XML data on the body)

There are several libraries that can help you to achieve this. A good start would be using **JAXB** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) for the first 2 steps, and then creating a **REST Client** using either Apache HTTPClient, Spring's RestTemplate or Jersey.

Comment: Thank you Rene L for coming back to me.  I was away for the last week but will start working on this now and will let you know how I'm getting on!